# Undefined Method Error in has_many Association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, web-applications

I have two models, User and QuestionEvent.

```
    class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    ...
    has_many :questions
    has_many :asked_questions, :class_name => 'QuestionEvent', :foreign_key => 'questioner_id'
    has_many :received_questions, :class_name => 'QuestionEvent', :foreign_key => 'respondent_id'
    end

    class QuestionEvent < ActiveRecord::Base
    ...
    belongs_to :question  
    belongs_to :questioner, :class_name => 'User'
    belongs_to :respondent, :class_name => 'User'
    end
```

When I call QuestionEvent.first.questioner or QuestionEvent.first.respondent, I get the expected user.  However, calling User.first.asked_questions gives me:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `asked_questions' for #<User:0x007fc687d53ae0>
```

Can anyone see what mistake I'm making here?

My database schema for QuestionEvent is:

```
  t.integer :question_id
  t.integer :questioner_id
  t.integer :respondent_id
```

Comment: Have you run migrations since adding the column?

Comment: Could you show your db schema?

Comment: @Russell I have, and it still doesn't work

Comment: @yoones Added it to the question, thanks.

Comment: Do calls to other user fields succeed? `User.first.questions` and `User.first.received_questions`?

Comment: Just to be sure, are you using a rails console? Because if you are, you need to restart it.

Comment: Also do you have a :user_id field in QuestionEvent?

Comment: @yoones Restarting the console was the solution, thanks for the help.

Comment: Please add your solution as answer @yoones

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You said that you solved you problem by restarting the console.  That's fine, but a better solution is to just run the command `reload!`.  That way, you don't have to restart.

Comment: I would also add re-running your query too

Answer (score 2):

You need to restart your rails console to take into account new changes.